# Nested mapping in solidity

Tags: mapping

this code require two input(_Id,_name) to get age
i need to get name and age from input id only

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;
contract nestmap
{
    mapping(uint256=>mapping(string=>uint256)) public User;
    function adduser(uint256 _Id,string memory _name, uint256 _age)public {
         User[_Id][_name]=_age;
    }
    
}
function user(uint256 _Id,string memory _name)public view returns(uint256)
    {
        return User[_Id][_name];
    }
```

Comment: Your nested `mapping` describes a data structure where each `id` has a large number of `string` keys, and each of those maps to a `uint256`, so probably not what you want. It's roughtly `key1 => key2 => value`, hence two keys are requested. I voted for Yongjian's answer. That's _probably_ what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract nestmap {

    struct Person{
        uint256 age;
        string name;
    }

    mapping (uint256 => Person) public User;

    function adduser(uint256 _Id, uint256 _age, string memory _name) public {
         User[_Id].age = _age;
         User[_Id].name = _name;
    }

    function user(uint256 _Id) public view returns(Person memory) {
        return User[_Id];
    }
}
```